# Magento2.4: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results tool doesn't validate the breadcrumbs properly

Tags: php, magento2.2, javascript, frontend, breadcrumbs

the results of testing the URL `https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/aamsco-unico-3-with-double-vertical-bands-of-led-lighting.html` with the tool  `https://search.google.com/test/rich-results` don't seem to say everything is fine.

When I run the same tool with the code copied from the inspect window as below and inserted under the CODE tab, I get the result as follows, which is correct.

[image]

We know that Google looks at the URL. Can you please tell me what is wrong with the URL that is making the tool report inaccurate results?

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is indexed successfully, webmasters can view details of the HTTP response and HTML code; also copy, search and validate for specific changes made by them. All HTTP response status codes are majorly separated into five classes or categories:

- 1xx informational response – the request was received, continuing process
- 2xx successful – the request was successfully received, understood, and accepted
- 3xx redirection – further action needs to be taken in order to complete the request
- 4xx client error – the request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled
- 5xx server error – the server failed to fulfil an apparently valid request